Error in VS Code: “Command 'Error Lens: Copy Problem Message' resulted in an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')”
I encountered an issue while using the Error Lens extension in Visual Studio Code. When I try to use the "Copy Problem Message" command, I get the following error popup:

Steps to Reproduce:
Make sure you have the ErrorLens extension installed in VSCode.
Try using the "Copy Problem Message" command.
System Information:
VS Code version: 1.96.2
Error Lens version: 3.22.0
OS: Windows 11
Attempts to Fix:
Restarted VS Code.
Reinstalled the Error Lens extension.
Questions:
Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks for the help.

Please, provide more details on how to reproduce the error. A step by step would be great. This "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')" kind of error normally occurs because the extension expects a regular document to be focused/selected, but didn't find one. Maybe you are focused on the terminal, a side panel or even no active document. It depends entirely on how the extension handles edge cases. That's why a step by step would is so important and could give a glimpse on the issue.
